# enviar e-mail por php usando mail()

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email

estou fazendo um site para uma emresa mas nao consigo fazer o codigo que envia o email fazer o tal estou usando a função mail do php

```
<?php 

$Enviadopor = $_POST['e'];
$Assunto= $_POST['a'];
$Mensagem= $_POST['msg'];

$corpomail= 'Fale Conosco - comdica.com 
    Email: '.$Email.'
    Assunto:' .$Assunto.'
    Mensagem:' .$Mensagem.'';

if (mail( 'julio.junior.301@comdica.epizy.com', $Assunto, $Mensagem)) {
    echo "mensagem enviada com sucesso";
}else{
    echo "mensagem nao enviada";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo funcional de envio de E-mail com php via POST..
neste caso eu fiz o envia das informações via Ajax.. mais vc pode ficar a vontade para implementar o front-end da forma que desejar! Utilizei também retornos em Json para exibir as msgns de erro e success no front!

Boa sorte!

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$filter_rules = [
    'name'      => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'email'     => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL,
    'phone'     => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'site'      => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
];
$validation = [
    'name' =>[
        'is_null'   => 'Preencha o campo <b>nome</b>!',
        'is_false'  => 'O Campo <b>nome</b> não é valido!'
    ],
    'email' =>[
        'is_null'   => 'Preencha o campo <b>e-mail</b>!',
        'is_false'  => 'O Campo <b>e-mail</b> não é valido!'
    ],
    'phone' =>[
        'is_null'   => 'Preencha o campo <b>Telefone</b>!',
        'is_false'  => 'O Campo <b>Telefone</b> não é valido!'
    ]
];
$data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filter_rules);
foreach ($data as $field => $value){
    if(empty($validation[$field])){
        continue;
    }
    if($value == null or $value == ''){
        echo json_encode(["status"=>false,"msg"=> $validation[$field]['is_null'] ]);exit;
    } elseif($value === false){
        echo json_encode(["status"=>false,"msg"=> $validation[$field]['is_false'] ]);exit;
    }

}
$email_sender = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
// Message
$message = '
    <html>
        <head>
          <title>Solicitação do cliente</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <p><b>Nome:</b>'.$data['name'] .'</p>
          <p><b>E-mail:</b>'.$data['email'] .'</p>
          <p><b>Telefone:</b>'.$data['phone'] .'</p>
          <p><b>Site:</b>'.$data['site'] .'</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    ';
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.1' ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' ."\r\n";
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: '. $email_sender ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: '. $email_sender ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $data['email'] ."\r\n";
// Mail it
if(mail('example@email.com', $subject, $message, $headers, "-f$email_sender")){
    echo json_encode(["status"=>true, "msg"=>"Mensagem enviada com <b>sucesso</b>!"]);exit;
}else {
    echo json_encode(["status"=>false, "msg"=>"Desculpe ocorreu um <b>erro</b>!"]);exit;
}
```

Comment: Em adição, verifique se a função mail() não está desativada no seu servidor e se o servidor SMTP e SMTP_PORT no php.ini está configurados corretamente na sessão [mail function]. Isso já me fez diferença!

Comment: Bem lembrado! vlw man

Comment: Mto obrigado por responder mas no final acabei usando a biblioteca do phpmailer que eu achei mais facil

Comment: Blz, brother. vlw